# How to define download name of image created on the fly using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, fancybox

We are using a PHP script (watermark.php) to change an image on the fly:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('../'.$_GET['url']));

$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);

// Load the watermark
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('../imgs/bgs/watermark.png');
$ww = imagesx($watermark);
$wh = imagesy($watermark);

// Insert watermark to the right bottom corner
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $w-$ww-15, $h-$wh-5, 0, 0, $ww, $wh);

// Send the image
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image,null,95);
```

This is placed in an anchor tag ready for use by fancybox:

```
<a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="scripts/watermark.php?url=SOME-IMG-TO-CHANGE-ON-THE-FLY.jpg">
<img src="imgs/btns/blanco.png">
</a>
```

Fancybox then uses the anchor tag to create this for it's lightbox:

```
<img class="fancybox-image" src="scripts/watermark.php?url=SOME-IMG-TO-CHANGE-ON-THE-FLY.jpg" style="display: inline;">
```

If the user wants to save the lightbox image by right clicking on it, s/he gets watermark.php as the file name to save to.

How do we get the filename to display as SOME-IMG-TO-CHANGE-ON-THE-FLY.jpg and not watermark.php??

We have tried hacking the fancybox code to output this:

```
<img class="fancybox-image" src="scripts/watermark.php?url=SOME-IMG-TO-CHANGE-ON-THE-FLY.jpg" download="SOME-IMG-TO-CHANGE-ON-THE-FLY.jpg" style="display: inline;">
```

but no luck so far. Any ideas how best to hack the fancybox code or other suggestions on how to solve this problem?

*Fancybox Version version: 3.0.0 Beta 1 (Tue, 29 Jan 2013)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a content-disposition header:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='foo.jpg'");
```

The `<img>` tag will show `/script.php?id=47`, but when someone tries to save-as the image, the browser will use the filename specified in the disposition header (`foo.jpg`).

Comment: I've been using this method for a long time, but adding the `content-type` too. Does it work only with the content-disposition? I guess I assumed it was needed without testing :$

Comment: Yeah, the filename has to go into the disposition header. the type header only allows mimetypes, so something like `image/jpeg; filename=...` wouldn't work.